# How can i pivot longer in R using dplyr with logical and character columns?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a dataframe that looks like this :

| id | month | C1 | C2 | C3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | TRUE | FALSE | ok |
| A | 2 | FALSE | FALSE | not |
| A | 3 | FALSE | TRUE | warning |
| B | 1 | TRUE | TRUE | not |
| B | 2 | FALSE | FALSE | not |
| B | 3 | TRUE | FALSE | ok |

And i want to pivot longer from wide in R in order to look like this :

| id | month | Check category | result |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | C1 | TRUE |
| A | 2 | C1 | FALSE |
| A | 3 | C1 | FALSE |
| A | 1 | C2 | FALSE |
| A | 2 | C2 | FALSE |
| A | 3 | C2 | TRUE |
| A | 1 | C3 | ok |
| A | 2 | C3 | not |
| A | 3 | C3 | warning |
| B | 1 | C1 | TRUE |
| B | 2 | C1 | FALSE |
| B | 3 | C1 | TRUE |
| B | 1 | C2 | TRUE |
| B | 2 | C2 | FALSE |
| B | 3 | C2 | FALSE |
| B | 1 | C3 | not |
| B | 2 | C3 | not |
| B | 3 | C3 | OK |

My effort in R is the following:

```
id = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3));id
month=c(1,2,3,1,2,3)
C1 = c(T,F,F,T,F,T);C1
C2 = c(F,F,T,T,F,F);C1
C3 = c("ok","not","wanrning","not","not","ok")
dat = tibble(id,month,C1,C2,C3);dat
dat%>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!c(id,month), names_to = "check_spot", values_to = c("control_check"))
```

But R reports me an error saying :

```
Error: Can't combine `C1` <logical> and `C3` <character>.
```

How can i fix this and take as an outpt the wanted table ?
Any help ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just change `logical` to `character` will helps.

```
dat%>%
  mutate(across(is.logical, ~as.character(.x))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!c(id,month), names_to = "check_spot", values_to = c("control_check"))

   id    month check_spot control_check
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        
 1 A         1 C1         TRUE         
 2 A         1 C2         FALSE        
 3 A         1 C3         ok           
 4 A         2 C1         FALSE        
 5 A         2 C2         FALSE        
 6 A         2 C3         not          
 7 A         3 C1         FALSE        
 8 A         3 C2         TRUE         
 9 A         3 C3         wanrning     
10 B         1 C1         TRUE         
11 B         1 C2         TRUE         
12 B         1 C3         not          
13 B         2 C1         FALSE        
14 B         2 C2         FALSE        
15 B         2 C3         not          
16 B         3 C1         TRUE         
17 B         3 C2         FALSE        
18 B         3 C3         ok
```

## reorder?

```
dat%>%
  mutate(across(is.logical, ~as.character(.x))) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(!c(id,month), names_to = "check_spot", values_to = c("control_check")) %>%
  arrange(id, check_spot)

   id    month check_spot control_check
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        
 1 A         1 C1         TRUE         
 2 A         2 C1         FALSE        
 3 A         3 C1         FALSE        
 4 A         1 C2         FALSE        
 5 A         2 C2         FALSE        
 6 A         3 C2         TRUE         
 7 A         1 C3         ok           
 8 A         2 C3         not          
 9 A         3 C3         wanrning     
10 B         1 C1         TRUE         
11 B         2 C1         FALSE        
12 B         3 C1         TRUE         
13 B         1 C2         TRUE         
14 B         2 C2         FALSE        
15 B         3 C2         FALSE        
16 B         1 C3         not          
17 B         2 C3         not          
18 B         3 C3         ok
```

Comment: i need a different arrange or group_by as i represent in the OP.

Comment: @HomerJaySimpson Do you mean you want exactly same order for that table as in question?

Comment: Simply add an `arrange()` to the end of the pipe provided by @Park.

Comment: the reorder edit works fine.thanks for your answer it was very helpful

Answer (score 1):

```
 dat %>%
    pivot_longer(-c(id,month), names_to = "check_spot", values_to = "control_check",
                values_transform = as.character)  %>%
   arrange(id, check_spot)

# A tibble: 18 x 4
   id    month check_spot control_check
   <chr> <dbl> <chr>      <chr>        
 1 A         1 C1         TRUE         
 2 A         2 C1         FALSE        
 3 A         3 C1         FALSE        
 4 A         1 C2         FALSE        
 5 A         2 C2         FALSE        
 6 A         3 C2         TRUE         
 7 A         1 C3         ok           
 8 A         2 C3         not          
 9 A         3 C3         wanrning     
10 B         1 C1         TRUE         
11 B         2 C1         FALSE        
12 B         3 C1         TRUE         
13 B         1 C2         TRUE         
14 B         2 C2         FALSE        
15 B         3 C2         FALSE        
16 B         1 C3         not          
17 B         2 C3         not          
18 B         3 C3         ok
```

Comment: `gather` and `spread` have been superseded in the latest versions of tidyr.

Comment: is not the needed output form

Comment: @Limey they were superseded long time ago. I was hoping to get the needed output